# Javascript function with parameters and prompt

Tags: javascript, php

I've got a problem with a Javascript function with 2 parameters.
The first parameter is a int and the secound a String with as many words as the user entered before. With only the first int parameter the function is working.

Here is my php code:

```
function createCodeAnf($query){
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) 
{ 
  $code = '<tr>
           <td>'.$info['cf_id'].'</td>
       <td>'.$info['res_sonst'].'</td>

       <a href="#" onclick="changeData('.$info['cf_id'].', '.$info['res_sonst'].')"><img src="css/images/progress.jpg"></a>
       </tr>';

  echo $code;
}
```

}

And here my JS function:

```
function changeData(user_id, sonst) {

var answer = confirm("Change Data?");
if(answer) {
    var x = prompt("Some Text here:", sonst);

        if(x){
            window.location = "http://www.somelink.com/progress.php?id=" + user_id + "&sonst=" + x;
        } else {
            return;
        }

} else {
    return;
}
```

}

Any suggestion?

Comment: Look at the **generated** HTML/JavaScript code. Do you notice any oddities? (hint: quotation marks)

Comment: You might want to describe the error, or where it is not working.How are you calling the JavaScript function? The `sonst` variable becomes the default text in the prompt but can then be replaced?

Comment: You need to quote your string parameters in `onclick` call.  Also you might want to fix the anchor tag within a `<tr>` tag outside `<td>`

Comment: I've tried quoting them, and the anchor tag is inside a <td>, just deleted the wrong part of the real code. It didn't work.

Comment: `INT` don't need quotes, `STRING` do. in this line `<a href="#" onclick="changeData('.$info['cf_id'].', '.$info['res_sonst'].')">` you are passing the second parameter as a string but no quotes, can you please add single quotes?, try it and let us know.

Comment: I've tried `$sonst = $info['res_sonst']; onclick="changeData('.$info['cf_id'].', "'.$sonst.'")"`, but it still does not work.

Comment: not sure, plus try replacing dots in plus (. => +)

Comment: you checked javascript console for any errors ?

Comment: Problem solved: `<a href="#" onclick="changeData(\''.$sonst.'\', \''.$id.'\')"><img src="css/images/progress.jpg"></a>`